# Clarification of Theorem 2.4.3 in Weibel (left derived functors are universal $\delta$-functors)

Tags: proof-explanation, homological-algebra

I am a little confused by the last two lines of Weibel's proof. Note that Weibel defines a $\delta$-functor $W_*$ to be universal when incoming morphisms $T_* \to W_*$ are completely characterized by $T_0 \Rightarrow W_0$.

The $\delta$-functor we wish to prove is universal is the left derived $\delta$-functor of a right exact functor $F$ from a category with enough projectives. Weibel defines natural transformations $\phi_n \colon T_n \Rightarrow L_n F$ and shows they are unique. Then he gets to the last bit where he needs to show that, given a short exact sequence, the relevant ladder commutes.

> Finally, we need to verify that $\varphi_n$ commutes with $\delta_n$.
> Given a short exact sequence $0 \to A' \to A \to A'' \to 0$ and a chosen exact sequence $0 \to K'' \to P'' \to A'' \to 0$ with $P''$ projective, we can construct maps $f$ and $g$ making the diagram
> $$
>   \require{AMScd}
>   \begin{CD}
>     0 @>>> K''     @>>> P''     @>>> A'' @>>> 0  \\
>     @.     @VV g V      @VV f V      @|       @. \\
>     0 @>>> A'      @>>> A       @>>> A'' @>>> 0
>   \end{CD}
> $$
> commute.
> This yields a commutative diagram
> $$
>   \begin{CD}
>     T_n(A'')
>     @> \delta >> T_{n - 1}(K'')
>     @> T(g) >> T_{n - 1}(A')
>     \\
>     @V \varphi_n VV
>     @VV \varphi_{n - 1} V
>     @VV \varphi_{n - 1} V
>     \\
>     L_n F(A'')
>     @> \delta >> L_{n - 1} F(K'')
>     @> L_n F(g) >> L_{n - 1} F(A').
>   \end{CD}
> $$
> Since the horizontal composites are the $\delta_n$ maps of the bottom row, this implies the desired commutativity relation.
>
> ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAFOu.png))

I understand why the squares at the end commute but not why $T(g) \circ \delta$ and $LF(g) \circ \delta$ are the desired maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the following axiom of a homological $\delta$-functor (since you're asking about Weibel, I present you the definition from Weibel):

> 2. For each morphism of short exact sequences from $0 \to A' \to B' \to C' \to 0$ to $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, the $\delta$’s give a commutative diagram
>    $$
>      \require{AMScd}
>      \begin{CD}
>        T_n(C') @> \delta >> T_{n - 1}(A') \\
>        @VVV                 @VVV          \\
>        T_n(C)  @> \delta >> T_{n - 1}(A)
>      \end{CD}
>      \qquad\text{resp.}\qquad
>      \begin{CD}
>        T^n(C') @> \delta >> T^{n + 1}(A') \\
>        @VVV                 @VVV          \\
>        T^n(C)  @> \delta >> T^{n + 1}(A).
>      \end{CD}
>    $$
>
> ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgCgL.png))

Note that, by functoriality, $T_n(1_{A''}) = 1_{T_n(A'')}$ and $L_nF(1_{A''}) = 1_{L_nF(A'')}$